# parsing specific content from local file in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a local file for all of the names of apps in it, and store it in an array. The file is structured like:

```
switcher-menu-config:
        instances:
          - radloc: [-0.5, 0, 0.99]
          - radloc: [0.5, 0, 0.99]
            right-justify: true
        menu-content:
         - appname: yamp
           label: Cognitive
           signal: yamp
           heartbeat: yamp-pulse
           message:
             descrips:
             - yamp
             - play
             ingests:
               movie: overture
               paused: false
           should-master-reset: false
         - appname: scrubs
           label: Health
           signal: scrubs
           heartbeat: scrubs-pulse
         - appname: sprockets
           label: Commerce
           signal: sprockets
           heartbeat: sprockets-pulse
           and so on.....
```

so what i need are the values after each instance of `appname:` stored in an array. So in this instance `[yamp, scrubs, sprockets]` i had an idea with regex,

```
fs.readFile('path/to/file', (err, data) => { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    var regexp = /appname: /g;
    var match, matches = [];
    while ((match = regexp.exec(data)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match);
}
})
```

but that will only give me the times it matches `appname:` and not the stuff after, naturally. Is there anything I can add to this loop to get the data I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YAML to JSON](https://www.json2yaml.com/) online tool.

Or use [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) from npm.

Comment: The js-yaml helps with getting the yaml parsed, but the issue of getting and storing the names of apps still remains.